# What is the correct default value for a MySQL decimal field?

Tags: mysql, decimal, default-value

I have a `decimal` field in my MySQL database. I have defined it as this:
`decimal(1,1) UNSIGNED NULL`. But I would like to set a default value for it like `7.0`, and this is the problem I have. Whenever I want to set this value, I get this error:

```
Invalid default value ...
```

I also tried to set it as `7,0` and `7` but it resulted the same error. What is the correct default value for a MySQL decimal field?

*Note: I am using Navicat for MySQL*

Comment: In a DECIMAL column declaration, the precision and scale can be (and usually is) specified;...The precision represents the number of significant digits that are stored for values, and the scale represents the number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point. - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html, in other words 1,1 is precision 1 scale 1 which is big enough for .7 but not 7.0 (which needs 2,1)

Comment: Got it. I have to declare it as `DECIMAL(2,1)` to be able to put `7.0` as a default value for it. Thanks for your comment. I had written it before but I did not pay attention to the example provided there.

Comment: Let's see the statement that is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 5):

In MySQL, when declaring `DECIMAL(P,S)` :

> The precision (P) represents the number of significant digits that are stored for values, and the scale (S) represents the number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point.

So in your example, `DECIMAL(1,1)` means at most 1 digit, and at most 1 digit after the dot... which doesn't really make sense.

To better understand, here are more examples:

- `DECIMAL(5,2)`: 5 digits, two of them being used for the fractional part. Hence, possible values range from -999.99 to 999.99
- `DECIMAL(5,0)`: no fractional part allowed, so it is equivalent to an integer with maximum 5 digits.

With `UNSIGNED`, the behavior is the same, but using a minus sign will throw an error.