# Mysql double length error

Tags: mysql

I want do column for percents.. 
I need write: 1.00, 2.00, 99.99, 100.. % 
How I can use double type for this?

Now I have:

```
Double(4,2)
```

But when I write 100 in column I get error:

> Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column

Comment: 'Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to problems. They are also subject to platform or implementation dependencies.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html - decimal may be a better data type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50781482/2667536) (`double`and `decimal` have the same syntax) or the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html):

> DOUBLE[(M,D)]
>
> M is the total number of digits and D is the number of digits following the decimal point. If M and D are omitted, values are stored to the limits permitted by the hardware. A double-precision floating-point number is accurate to approximately 15 decimal places.

In short, `DOUBLE(4,2)` means at most 4 digits, with 2 digits **after the decimal point**. So to support two digits decimals until `100`, you need:

```
double(5,2) unsigned
```

Note that the `unsigned` is not mandatory, but can be more performant and safe if you know you won't need negative values.

Answer (score 0):

`double(4,2)` means a double with a total of four digits, two of them right of the decimal point, meaning you only have 4-2=2 digits to the left of it. `100` has three digits to the left of the decimal point, hence the error. Using `double(5,2)` instead should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html)

MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax:

```
FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D).
Here, (M,D) means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, 
of which D digits may be after the decimal point.
```

For example,
a column defined as **FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999 when displayed**.

*MySQL performs rounding when storing values*, so if you insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is 999.0001

Coming to your problem, you need to increase size of M. i.e. `Double(5,2)`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed one more thing will help someone.

IN `DOUBLE(M,D)` **M** is represent number of total digit including **D**, and **D** is represent the numbers after decimal,

If some one assign same value of **M** and **D** then you can only set value after decimal point but not before it.

Here i try to explain with an example,

If you want assign data type value like `DOUBLE(5,5)`, so you can only enter a value like 0.00001 to 0.99999 but you can not 1.0001 or 1.0000.

There is also limit of assign **D**, you can not assign **D** greater then to **M**, its only **M >= D**